# Rails custom reset password email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, locomotivecms

I have a project that is built on `LocomtiveCMS`, which already has reset password functionality built in. However, the reset password email it currently sends has just a basic skeleton wording.

How do I make a custom message to use in the email sent out for resetting a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your main app, all you have to do is to add a new file at this location: /app/views/locomotive/devise_mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.haml.

After a restart of your server, Devise should use this file as the new template for the reset password instructions.

We did that for LocomotiveHosting.com (which is built on top on the LocomotiveCMS engine) and it works well.

Thanks!

Did

Comment: For anyone else who reads this, I would add that I also had to add string values to the file at  app/config/locales/en.yml to use in haml file